# Class attributes not found in the interface that is implemented by this class

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection

My question may be complicated , but I will try to explain it . Suppose that I have a Interface called IA and class called A ,

**Interface IA:**

```
  public interface IA
    {
       public void Test();
    }
```

**Class A**

```
  public class A : IA
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public A()
          {
          }
    }
```

When I'm trying to use Dependency injection :

**Main Class :**

```
 public class MainClass
    {
      IA objectA = new A();
      objectA.Name = "test A"; // Not working , I didn't get this Name and I can't find it .
    }
```

> IA does not contains a definition for Name ...

What's the reason of this problem?

Comment: "What's the reason of this problem?" -> you need to learn how C# works, because what you want is not possible in a statically typed language. `IA` does not contain a definition for `Name`, `A` does. Your example does not follow SOLID principles

Comment: So I should create the same attribute in interface?

Comment: If `IA` should have a `Name` attribute, then yes. If not, this is not the solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve

Comment: What if I have another classes that implement this interface and they didn't needed this attribute and methods that use this attribute ?

Comment: Then, again, this is not the correct solution to the problem. This reads like an XY situation.  SOLID states that you should be able to change "A" for "B" if they both implement "IA" and everything should work in exactly the same way (for the consumer). If you depend on stuff specific for A, you have an incorrect structure

Comment: Also you cant put the line objectA.Name = "test A"; there anyway it would have to be within a method. Have a look at my Gist below

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Gist https://gist.github.com/ian-bowyer/f1a57a5fc8e4df41cc63d9816276d708 with the code on.

I changed IA to IApple and A to Apple.

The reason is that you have created an variable of type IApple (which then does not have the Name Property in it)

```
IA objectA = new A();
```

This says create me a variable called `objectA` of this interface `IA` using the constructor `A()`. The `objectA` will have the shape of the interface `(IA)` and not your `A` (object).

If you are wanting to have Name using the code then perhaps add it to the interface to make it available.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you create a Instance of interface class?
Try to create Instance of Class A like:

```
 public class MainClass
    {
      A objectA = new A();
      objectA.Name = "test A"; 
    }
```

So you can get your Test() Method and Name Property.

Or you put Name Property in Interface Class IA and all classes inherited from this Interface have Name Property.

Comment: Sorry , but this is not a solution , however, I would like to use interface to apply SOLID principales and to apply OOP concept

Comment: The code in the answer could have been fixed at least to compile (by putting the statements inside a method). Here it's just as bad as the question.

Comment: @Spi I stand corrected  `objectA.Name = "test A";`  doesn't make sense in the class body. Updated by Gist